# How to set default values while passing hash as an argument to ruby method?

Tags: ruby

Is there any better way to set default values of `hash` parameters in below ruby `method`?

```
def sent_email(args)
  args[:file_type] = 'html' if args[:file_type].nil?
  args[:css_tag] = 'title' if args[:css_tag].nil?
  args[:occurrence] = 'last' if args[:occurrence].nil?
end
```

I want to build such `method`, when no arguments are passed, then it should take default values of hash.

If such method is called without an arguments, then it should not give below error.

`1.9.3-p0 :040 > sent_email`

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

Comment: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments

Comment: You could [`merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) default values into the given hash.

Comment: What is `hash`?

Comment: What is `method`?

Comment: @sawa why are you asking such questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it better?

```
args[:file_type] ||= 'html'


> args = {file_type: 'html', css_tag: 'title'}
# => {:file_type=>"html", :css_tag=>"title"} 
> args[:file_type] ||= 'last'
# => "html" 
> args[:occurence] ||= 'last'
# => "last" 
> args
# => {:file_type=>"html", :css_tag=>"title", :occurence=>"last"}
```

**EDIT**

```
DEFAULTS = {file_type: "html", css_tag: "title", occurence: "last"}
args = {}
others = {file_type: "xml", css_tag: "h1"}

DEFAULTS.merge(args) # => {:file_type=>"html", :css_tag=>"title", :occurence=>"last"}
DEFAULTS.merge(others) # => {:file_type=>"xml", :css_tag=>"h1", :occurence=>"last"}
```

Comment: is there any better way to dry those three lines?

Comment: sure, use `merge`  as @Stefan proposed. see my update.

Comment: I want to use this logic inside the `method`, so that method can be called without passing an arguments.

Comment: `merge` idea is not useful in this case.

Comment: @Rhunal what do you mean the method can be called without passing arguments? You mean you want a `Hash`?

Comment: @engineersmnky I want to pass hash as an argument to the method, please see the answer below.

Comment: @Rhunal this answer is the DRYest version as requested and can easily be adapted to a method. eg `def sent_email(args={}); DEFAULTS.merge(args);end`